# Containerizing a Spring boot application with Docker error

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am trying to containerize my Spring application with Docker. However, Docker cannot find my jar file.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16-jre-hotspot
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} rtv-1.jar /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/rtv-1.jar"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    volumes:
      - absolutepathtothedircontaining "rtv-1":/app
  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=compose-postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
```

When I run docker-compose up I am still having the same error.

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You're copying your jar into /app but trying to run it from /.

Comment: I have just tried to modify the dockerfile to :
FROM adoptopenjdk:16-jre-hotspot
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} rtv-1.jar /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/rtv-1.jar"]

Comment: It's still not working should I modify the docker file?

Comment: Does the `COPY` line intend to change the filename; `COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app/rtv-1.jar`?  If so, the `volumes:` will hide what's in the image, and you should delete that block.  (You'll always have to recompile a Java application, so using `volumes:` to simulate a live-reloading local development environment doesn't make sense here.)

Comment: Have you tried exec'ing into your container with a bash shell and just looking around? What kind of debugging are you doing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure, `rtv-1.jar` file and `Dockerfile` file are in the same folder.

Just copy `rtv-1.jar`  file to `/app` folder.

```
COPY rtv-1.jar /app
```

its a wrong path:

Change it : `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/rtv-1.jar"]`

To : `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "rtv-1.jar"]`

Or :   `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/rtv-1.jar"]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried the change still not working with same error.

Comment: just edited the answer, please re-check

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked with ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "rtv-1.jar"]

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:16-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${JAR_FILE} rtv-1.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/rtv-1.jar"]
```